# PHP - Array of constant objects

Tags: php, object, constants

i have an array of objects. Like the code below:

```
Class fileHeadFootBlock {
        public $offset;
        public $id;
        public $length;
        public $version;
    }

    $FILE_HEADER = array(); // This array contains all file header block constant
    //race1UP file version
    $FH_FILEVER = new fileHeadFootBlock();
    $FH_FILEVER->offset = 18;
    $FH_FILEVER->id = hexdec('FF');
    $FH_FILEVER->length = hexdec('3E');
    $FH_FILEVER->version = 'File ver: v.20120521 beta (gen from matlab)';
    array_push($FILE_HEADER, $FH_FILEVER);
    //race1UP hardware version
    $FH_RERHWVER = new fileHeadFootBlock();
    $FH_RERHWVER->offset = $FH_FILEVER->offset + $FH_FILEVER->length;
    $FH_RERHWVER->id = hexdec('FE');
    $FH_RERHWVER->length = hexdec('60');
    $FH_RERHWVER->version = 'HARDWARE VERSION: v.20120521 beta.';
    array_push($FILE_HEADER, $FH_RERHWVER);
```

The array of objects, of type fileHeadFootBlock, is $FILE_HEADER

The question is the following:
Which is the best way to make the $FILE_HEADER constant? Each element of the array and its fields ($offset, $id. $length, $version) should be costants.

regards,
Alex

Comment: Why do they need to be constants?

Comment: I solved make it private member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want keep your data filed can not be changed. You can make them private and only set in constructor.

There is example:

```
Class fileHeadFootBlock {
    private $offset;
    private $id;
    private $length;
    private $version;

    public function __construct($offset, $id, $length, $version)
    {
        $this->offset = $offset;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->length = $length;
        $this->version = $version;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOffset()
    {
        return $this->offset;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLength()
    {
        return $this->length;
    }
}

$FILE_HEADER = array();
//race1UP file version
$FH_FILEVER = new fileHeadFootBlock(18, 'FF', '3E', 'File ver: v.20120521 beta (gen from matlab)');
array_push($FILE_HEADER, $FH_FILEVER);
//race1UP hardware version
$FH_RERHWVER = new fileHeadFootBlock($FH_FILEVER->getOffset() + $FH_FILEVER->getLength(), 'FE', '60', 'HARDWARE VERSION: v.20120521 beta.');
array_push($FILE_HEADER, $FH_RERHWVER);
```